# possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I have the following in configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_PROGS(MAKE,$MAKE make gmake,error)
if test "x$MAKE" = "xerror" ;then
  AC_MSG_ERROR([cannot find a make command])
fi
```

This has been in our project for a long time, but in some set ups, I get this error:

```
configure.ac:45: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
```

The lines that were recently added above this:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
LT_INIT
```

Can anyone explain what causes this error and how to track down the problem?

**EDIT:** Adding details about the differences.

Box that works:

```
uname -a Linux host1 2.6.38-13-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 28 19:33:45 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

automake: 1.11.1
autoconf: 2.67
m4: 1.4.14
libtoolize: 2.2.6b
```

Box that doesn't work:

```
Linux host2 2.6.32-35-generic-pae #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 17:01:12 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

automake: 1.11.1
autoconf: 2.65
m4: 1.4.13
libtoolize: 2.2.6b
```

**NEW EDIT:** only 32 bit machines experience this difficulty.

**UPDATED** I am able to reproduce the problem on a CentOS machine with `autoconf 2.67`, `automake 1.11.1`, `libtool 2.2.6b`, and `m4 1.4.14`. Is this just a bug with 32-bit machines?

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Build your tarballs with autoconf 2.67.  You only need to have autoconf installed on one machine!

Comment: I am aware I can work around the issue easily, I'm just trying to make sure its an issue with the one box and not a problem in our configure.ac or other config files.

Comment: I know that autoconf 2.64 was considered fairly buggy.  Possibly you are experiencing a bug in 2.65.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem on another 32-bit machine with autoconf 2.67, automake 1.11.1, libtool 2.2.6b, and m4 1.4.14

Comment: I cannot imagine this helping: but have you tried AC_CHECK_PROGS([MAKE],[$MAKE make gmake],[error]) ? It definitely sounds like an m4 issue, and fully quoting things to m4 can only help.  This particular line is probably not the culprit, but it smells like a quoting issue somewhere.  Can you post the full configure.ac?

Comment: The entire file is over 2000 lines long, but it is part of the TORQUE open source project. You can check out the source svn co svn://svn.clusterresources.com/torque/trunk

Answer (score 322, accepted):

I had this same issue and found that `pkg-config` package was missing.

After installing the package, everything generated correctly.

Comment: I had the same issue as well, specifically this error message: "If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the Autoconf documentation." and it was also a case of missing pkg-config.

Comment: Thanks! Outlining my case, for the next guy in the same shoes. For the sake of having reproducible builds I have to use a toolchain of custom paths to all GNU Build System tools. The equivalent of installing pkg-config was not only to modify PATH but also to add `"-I /toolchain_local/pkg-config-0.23/share/aclocal"` to the `autoreconf` commandline. Took me some time to realize that pkg-config does not install only binaries. `rpm -ql pkgconfig` helped.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Just had this when trying to build glusterfs on a brand new FreeBSD build (which now uses pkgconf, and works with it).

Comment: I had to install `libtool`.

Comment: Just FYI technically this isn't fixing the problem.  In this case the `AC_MSG_ERROR` was trying to say "you need to install pkg-config" but for some reason it was unable to print this message (giving the error about `AC_MSG_ERROR`).  By installing `pkg-config` there was no longer any need to print an error message, so the `AC_MSG_ERROR` line was skipped and things work.  Fine if you are installing someone else's package, but if it's your own code, you still haven't fixed the problem :-)

Comment: I've encountered this issue before, and installing the ```autoconf-archive``` package fixed the issue.

Comment: Wow, this is an example of autoreconfig spitting out a really bad error message.

Comment: Fixed the broken built of rocket-chip on debian testing for me. Thnx!

Answer (score 34):

It is recommended to use `autoreconf -fi` instead of manually calling `aclocal;autoconf;automake; #and whatever else` to properly populate aclocal.m4 and so on.

Adding `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4` (to the toplevel Makefile.am) and `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` is currently still optional if you do not use any own m4 files, but of course, doing it will silence the proocess :)

Comment: We have m4 files, so that is required for us. Also, changing things to autoreconf -fi produces the same error.

Comment: If you do have m4 files, ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS and AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR is exactly what you should do. (And putting the files in m4/, resp. the dir that you specified)

Comment: I had this exact same problem and found that I'd missed out setting `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` in `Makefile.am` - thanks!

Comment: Autotools are so broken... None of this crap makes sense. How can it be in 30 years things are still this broken?

Answer (score 32):

I had this problem with my own `configure.ac`, but in this case (and for the benefit of anyone here from Google) it was because I had accidentally quoted the `AC_MSG_ERROR` so it was being treated as a string:

```
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.42], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find Boost])])
```

Once I removed the square brackets around the `AC_MSG_ERROR` macro, it worked:

```
AX_BOOST_BASE([1.42], [], AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find Boost]))
```

Those comments saying you should install `pkg-config` or some package are missing the point.  The `AC_MSG_ERROR` is supposed to work and give you a helpful message like "You need to install package XYZ", but because of some problem, the `AC_MSG_ERROR` doesn't work.  Installing package XYZ will certainly make the error go away, but only because once the package is there, there is no longer any need to print an error message!

So installing `pkg-config` or a particular package just bypasses the problem, it doesn't actually fix it.

Comment: It makes error gone. But will throw error on ./configure script

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem on RHEL7.5 with otto-de/libvmod-uuid

It was fixed by installing "autoconf-archive" packages

Comment: I needed "autoconf-archive" Debian package to build powertop v2,31-rc1.

Comment: I needed this to build tpm2-tools

Comment: needed for python on macos

Answer (score 13):

i also had similar problem.. my solution is to

```
apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

(i had libcurl allready installed )
worked for me at least..

Answer (score 11):

I have experienced this same problem under CentOS 7

In may case, the problem went off after installation of `libcurl-devel` (`libcurl` was already installed on this machine)

Answer (score 7):

There are two possible reasons for that problem:

1. did not install aclocal.
   solution：install libtool

   - For ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install libtool`
   - For centos: `sudo yum install libtool`
2. the path to LIBTOOL.m4 is error.
   solution:

   1. use `aclocal --print-ac-dir` to check current path to aclocal.(It's usually should be "/usr/share/aclocal" or "/usr/share/aclocal")
   2. Then check if there are *.m4 files.
   3. If not, cp corresponding *.m4 files to this path.( Maybe `cp /usr/share/aclocal/*.m4 /usr/local/share/aclocal/` or `cp /usr/local/share/aclocal/*.m4 /usr/share/aclocal/`)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

I just lost a few hours on this one. My conclusion:

- Depending on version and whatever other local conditions, autoconf will spit out the message about AC_MSG_ERROR undefined when it encounters *ANY undefined macro*. The AC_MSG_ERROR is a red herring. The causes for an undefined macro can be:

  - A typo in a macro name in the file, or a local macro which has not been shipped with the tarball
  - Missing a package which would have come with a set of autoconf macros, one of which is used in the file. pkg-config is often the missing one (because of, e.g.,PKG_CHECK_MODULES), but this could be any other package supplying a needed but absent macro. The vicious thing of course, is that this happens before the still not existing configure script could check for the missing package...

Comment: This is the answer!  Ultimately this is a bad error message from autoconf.

Answer (score 4):

For Debian. 
Required packages are:
m4 automake pkg-config libtool

Answer (score 3):

Are you setting up a local '`m4`' directory? e.g.,

`> aclocal -I m4 --install`

Some packages come with an `autogen.sh` or `initgen.sh` shell script to run glibtoolize, autoheader, autoconf, automake. Here's an `autogen.sh` script I use:

```
#! /bin/sh

case `uname` in Darwin*) glibtoolize --copy ;;
  *) libtoolize --copy ;; esac

autoheader
aclocal -I m4 --install
autoconf

automake --foreign --add-missing --force-missing --copy
```

**EDIT**

You may need to add `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4` to the top-level `Makefile.am`.

Comment: Does autoreconf not select the proper libtoolize on Darwin?

Comment: I am setting up a local 'm4' directory. I added -I m4 --install to aclocal, but I get the same error. This is my autogen.sh script: libtoolize -c -f
autoheader -f
aclocal -I m4 --install
autoconf -f
automake --foreign --add-missing --force-missing --copy

Comment: @dbeer, added the `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` variable?

Comment: @WilliamPursell no, it doesn't. MacOS features the GNU libtool as 'glibtool', and the one provided by Apple (which doesn't behave like expected by a GNU libtool) as 'libtool'. Note that also libtoolize is installed as 'glibtoolize'. This can be overriden by specifying LIBTOOLIZE and LIBTOOL macro. Despite this autogen sample is good, it's often better to simply run autoreconf -fi and let it guess/recover the -I flag from the previous run, especially when the software isn't yours.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac OS X el captain with brew, try:
brew install pkgconfig

This worked for me.

Comment: This needs more upvotes, adding comment for visibility

Answer (score 2):

The error is generated by autom4te.  If things are set up correctly, the portion of the code that generates that error should never see 'AC_MSG_ERROR', because it should have been expanded by m4 before that point.  You say the error only happens "in some setups".  I would suggest that in those setups, your autoconf installation is fubar.  Possibly you have an incompatible version of m4 installed.

Comment: I am on autoconf 2.65 and m4 1.4.13. Are these compatible?

Comment: m4 1.4.13 is new enough and is not likely the problem.  Can you determine what is different about the setups in which you see the warning from those in which you do not?

Comment: I just added some of the information on that to my question - can you think of anything else relevant? I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to autotools.

Comment: Just noticed - 32 bit machines seem to be the ones with difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

Using MacOS X

```
sudo port install pkgconfig
```

was the solution!

Comment: this answer is outdated, use brew instead of port

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues when trying to build amtk and utthpmock with jhbuild.

I needed to install the most recent version of autoconf-archive. Instructions are at https://github.com/autoconf-archive/autoconf-archive/blob/master/README-maint. I did an additional `sudo make install` at the end.

The last step was to update my `ACLOCAL_PATH`:

```
echo 'export ACLOCAL_PATH=$ACLOCAL_PATH:/usr/local/share/aclocal' >> ~/.bashrc
```

After a `source ~/.bashrc`, all the macros were finally found and the builds succeeded.

Comment: This is the solution if someone met this problem on macos.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu (`error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR`) but the answers above didn't work for me. I found the solution [here](http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/04/configure-possibly-undefined-macro.html)

That did the trick:

```
$ LANG=C LC_CTYPE=C ./autogen.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved after I install pkg-config on Mac (brew install pkg-config)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by `yum install libtool`

Comment: after I finish compile pkg-config

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I forgot a , in the arguments for a locally defined macro.  Spent hours trying to figure it out (barely acquainted with autotools)...

```
AC_CHECK_MACRO([Foo]
    AC_LOCAL_DO([......
```

should have been

```
AC_CHECK_MACRO([Foo],      # <-- Notice comma, doh!
    AC_LOCAL_DO([......
```

Seems like it should have given me an error or such, but I suppose being a macro processor it can only do what its told.

Answer (score 0):

you are pulling automake in one version / location and autoconf in another.  you either want to remove the offending autoconf or automake from your path and make sure you have the right version

Comment: Although Automake works as an adjunct to Autoconf, the two are separate projects.  They are not version-locked with each other.  There is *some* version dependency, but the combination of versions that this 10-year-old question claims were in use is a working one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem bootstrapping (autoreconf) PC/SC lite on Debian bullseye (with up-to-date autotools installed). The reason was simple: the two M4 macros AX_PTHREAD and AX_RECURSIVE_EVAL were not defined.
So I googled the .m4 files, downloaded them, copied them into /usr/share/aclocal and it finally worked.
GNU autotools are a common source for problems. If you can just perform: "./configure && make" you are a lucky person.
If you have to use autoreconf because you have to modify configure.ac et.al., then many many problems can stop this stuff from working:

- wrong/outdated versions of autotools installed
- very old configure.ac and/or Makefile.am files

The debugging steps posted above are correct and helpful, though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the Macports port "openocd" (locally modified the Portfile to use the git repository) on a freshly installed machine.

The permanent fix is easy, define a dependency to pkgconfig in the Portfile:
    depends_lib-append  port:pkgconfig