# Linphone configuration results in multiple undefined Autotools macros

Tags: windows, build, autotools, mingw32, linphone

I have downloaded the Linphone opensource and build using MINGW. I have followed the steps given by the README.mingw. When I use the command "./autogen.sh", I got the following error.

```
+ aclocal -I m4 -I /usr/local/share/aclocal -I /share/aclocal
aclocal:m4/po.m4:36: warning: macro `AM_PATH_PROG_WITH_TEST' not found in librar
y
aclocal:m4/po.m4:61: warning: macro `AM_PATH_PROG_WITH_TEST' not found in librar
y
aclocal:m4/po.m4:78: warning: macro `AM_PATH_PROG_WITH_TEST' not found in librar
y
aclocal:m4/gettext.m4:170: warning: macro `AM_ICONV_LINK' not found in library
configure.ac:185: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/intltool.m4:27: IT_PROG_INTLTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/po.m4:23: AM_PO_SUBDIRS is expanded from...
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_PREPARE_PREFIX is m4_require'd but not m4_defu
n'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_RPATH is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_ICONV_LINKFLAGS_BODY is m4_require'd but not m4_de
fun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
+ autoheader
configure.ac:185: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/intltool.m4:27: IT_PROG_INTLTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/po.m4:23: AM_PO_SUBDIRS is expanded from...
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_PREPARE_PREFIX is m4_require'd but not m4_defu
n'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_RPATH is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_ICONV_LINKFLAGS_BODY is m4_require'd but not m4_de
fun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
+ automake --force-missing --add-missing --copy
configure.ac:185: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/intltool.m4:27: IT_PROG_INTLTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/po.m4:23: AM_PO_SUBDIRS is expanded from...
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_PREPARE_PREFIX is m4_require'd but not m4_defu
n'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_RPATH is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_ICONV_LINKFLAGS_BODY is m4_require'd but not m4_de
fun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
src/Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac'
/usr/local/share/automake-1.9/am/depend2.am: am__fastdepOBJC does not appear in
AM_CONDITIONAL
tester/Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.a
c'
tools/Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac
'
/usr/local/share/automake-1.9/am/depend2.am: am__fastdepOBJC does not appear in
AM_CONDITIONAL
+ autoconf
configure.ac:185: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/intltool.m4:27: IT_PROG_INTLTOOL is expanded from...
configure.ac:185: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/po.m4:23: AM_PO_SUBDIRS is expanded from...
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_PREPARE_PREFIX is m4_require'd but not m4_defu
n'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AC_LIB_RPATH is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_ICONV_LINKFLAGS_BODY is m4_require'd but not m4_de
fun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure.ac:194: warning: AM_NLS is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gettext.m4:57: AM_GNU_GETTEXT is expanded from...
configure.ac:194: the top level
configure:16639: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_NLS
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure:17116: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_PROG_WITH_TEST
configure:17194: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIB_PREPARE_PREFIX
configure:17195: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIB_RPATH
configure:17196: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_ICONV_LINKFLAGS_BODY
configure:17365: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_ICONV_LINK
configure:17367: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIB_LINKFLAGS_BODY
configure:17500: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_LIB_APPENDTOVAR
```

I have searched in the internet. But I didn't get any solution. Please can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: Did you compile linphone successfully? I try lot but each time get new errors. My old post :- http://nongnu.13855.n7.nabble.com/Linphone-EXE-compilation-problem-td182023.html

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because homebrew installs to /usr/local, and Linphone is coded to assume macports' standard install prefix of /opt/local.

You can fix this specific problem by editing submodules/linphone/autogen.sh and changing the paths that start with /opt/local to /usr/local:

```
if test -d /usr/local/share/aclocal ; then
    ACLOCAL_ARGS="-I /usr/local/share/aclocal"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error on Mavericks OSX10.9 when installing using homebrew. The recommendation I've found is make sure you have pkg-config installed. Unfortunately, that fix hasn't worked for me but it might for you. See: [possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811381/possibly-undefined-macro-ac-msg-error)