# Autorreconf and "error: possibly undefined macro: AM_NLS"

Tags: autotools, configure, fedora-25

I'm trying to produce a `configure` script for [systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/systemd/systemd.git
$ cd systemd

$ autoreconf -i
configure.ac:74: warning: macro 'AM_NLS' not found in library
configure.ac:74: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_NLS
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

I'm on a fairly modern machine that's fully patched. Its Fedora 25, x86_64:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description:    Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
Release:        25
Codename:       TwentyFive
```

I'm not an Autotools expert, and searching for *"error: possibly undefined macro: AM_NLS"* is not returning useful hits for me. I found [Linphone configuration results in multiple undefined Autotools macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17809961/608639), but its not exactly clear what I should do. Unix & Linux Stack Exchange has [Some M4 macros don't seem to be defined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18673/56041), but its still not clear what I should do for this issue.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the problem and how do I fix it?

The problem is it's expecting [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/), specifically on Fedora 25 [gettext-devel](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/25/x86_64/g/gettext-devel-0.19.8.1-3.fc25.i686.html).  It's in `/usr/share/aclocal/nls.m4` contained in that package.  You should be able to install that package and build.

Comment: Thank you very much. Who comes up with these incomprehensible error messages? What is so broken in the Autotools engineering process they can't finish with, *"Please install gettext or ensure it is on-path"*?

Comment: `AM_NLS` isn't part of automake so they can't intuit what needs to be installed.  Maybe running [autogen.sh](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/autogen.sh) would have given you more information also, as that script bootstraps the build.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `apt-file` can be very useful in cases like this. Especially if you're able to guess that you probably need a file called `nls.m4`. E.g.  `apt-file find nls.m4` will give you 
`gettext` and `gnulib` as possible sources for that file.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `apt-file` won't help on Fedora.  But `dnf provides '*nls.m4'` might help.    IIRC, I searched [rpmfind.net](http://rpmfind.net/) or something like that for the package after decoding the error.