# AS_IF and AC_MSG_ERROR: error: possibly undefined macro

Tags: autotools, autoconf, autogen, libnice

I encounter such errors when trying to build libnice-0.1.10. For solution, I am following [possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811381/possibly-undefined-macro-ac-msg-error), but still not getting there.

some program version

```
uname: 3.5.0-23-generic
m4: 1.4.16
automake: 1.14.1
autoconf: 2.69
libtoolize: 2.4.2
```

I also add `ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /.../share/aclocal"` in `~/.bashrc`.

Here is what is reported from `autogen.sh`.

```
$ ./autogen.sh
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: copying file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `m4'.
libtoolize: copying file `m4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:331: warning: PKG_PROG_PKG_CONFIG is m4_require'd but not m4_defun'd
m4/gtk-doc.m4:7: GTK_DOC_CHECK is expanded from...
configure.ac:331: the top level
configure.ac:105: error: possibly undefined macro: AS_IF
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac:218: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR
autoreconf: /opt/oblong/deps-64-10/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Do you have [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) installed? See if: `/.../share/aclocal/pkg.m4` exists. It shouldn't be necessary to set `ACLOCAL_INCLUDE` - that directory is already part of autoconf - and it might prevent searching in the libnice `m4` directories.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This just means you're missing pkg-config (or perhaps you have an old version). Just download and install.

Comment: I made sure that pkg-config is installed and I have /usr/share/aclocal/pkg.m4 on my system.  I still got an error when using the following: ACX_PTHREAD([AC_DEFINE([HAVE_PTHREAD] ...).  The error is configure.ac:31: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DEFINE.  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow. So there are possible other causes.

Comment: You should detail the troubleshooting steps that results in the conclusion `pkg-config` is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing the autoconf-archive collection of macros (`AC_MSG_ERROR` is one of those macros included in this package)

Run `autoreconf -vi` then run `./configure` and the actual error will be shown on the screen.